# How do I modify my code to skip comments when counting number of lines? C++

Tags: comments

I know this statement below lets me skip spaces when I am counting  number of lines in my code, but I need to modify this to detect if a "//" is at the beginning of the line it'll skip it also.

Thank you for any advice.

```
// some snippets of the code 
char line;
fstream file;
file.open ("myfile.cpp")
while (file.good())
{
   line=file.get();

if (line == ' ')  // skip spaces
{
continue;
}

else if (line == '\n') // check to see if \n, then count as a line of code. 
{
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: You have not specified what happens on `//` comments with the final end of line character... Does it count or not for the total amount of lines?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify which language are you using...

Maybe you can use something like

```
if (line.startsWith("//"))
{
continue;
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I am using C++ on Ubuntu.